# TFS Backlog - how to know which PBI is assigned to which sprint

Tags: tfs

I have a very long backlog list with PBIs.

When I move a PBI to a sprint it does not get removed from the backlog and it can become a long process of planning the next sprint because I can't see which PBI is already assigned to the current sprint.

Sometimes , I need to add more PBIs to the current sprint and it is not visible from the backlog view to check if they are already assigned to a sprint that I want to assign them to.

How can I create a column that can tell me from the backlog that this specific PBI is planned in e.g. sprint 1.

Is there another solution to this?

Answer (score 0):

There is a column called "**Iteration Path**", you can see which sprint is assigned to for the specific PBI.

If the **Iteration Path** column doesn't appear, just click **Column options** >> select and add it from **Available columns** >> **OK**

[image]